# ASP.NET MVC 4 to ASP.NET Web API - Error: Only 'http' and 'https' schemes are allowed. Parameter name: requestUri

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

ASP.NET MVC throws the following error in TEST Server, which I could not reproduce in Developer machines.

Trying to connect to WebAPI Service from MVC and getting the error

**Only 'http' and 'https' schemes are allowed.  Parameter name: requestUri**

I could not get an answer from other questions since they are mainly talking about WCF bindings.

**Code:**

```
var credentials = "username:Password";
var encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentials));
this.client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", encoded);
System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(URL).Result;
```

**Note:** Accessing the WebAPI URL through browser returns the data.

Comment: Can you please post the exact code you are using the make the call from MVC?

Comment: It looks as though your issue is the contents of `URL`, can you update your question to show what `URL` is being set to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In anticipation of what might or might not be in your `URL` parameter, I'm guessing it doesn't start with `http://` or `https://`.  For this to work, it must start with one of these two.

So if your `URL` currently reads (assuming `URL` is a `string`):

```
mycompany.com/myservices
```

It needs changing to either:

```
http://mycompany.com/myservices
```

Or

```
https://mycompany.com/myservices
```

If `URL` isn't a `string`, but is instead an instance of `System.Uri`, then you need to do a similar thing when creating this object, or set the `URL.Scheme`.

Comment: In DEV environment using Visual Studio and IIS Express, I wasn't having any trouble. Once I moved to a IIS server in Test machine and configured as different applications, got this issue. Thank you for your answer and it solved the issue.